# Sending arbitrarily long string over Java TCP socket

Tags: java, string, sockets, networking, tcp

I have an Android app that communicates over a TCP socket with a server I wrote. The method I'm using now to read and write output works fine for smaller strings (up to 60kB) but I get an exception thrown when the string is much longer than that. Here is the relevant part of what I have for the server and client:

Server:

```
            DataInputStream dis = null;
            DataOutputStream dos = null;

            try {
                    dis = new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());
                    dos = new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());

                    String input = "";
                    input = dis.readUTF();
                    handle_input info = new handle_input(input, id);
                    String xml = info.handle();

                    dos.writeUTF(xml);

                    server.close();

            }
```

Client:

```
        Socket socket = null; 
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        DataInputStream dis = null;
        Boolean result;

        try {
            socket = new Socket(ip, port);
            dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            dos.writeUTF(the_text);
            String in = "";
            while (in.equals("")) {
                in += dis.readUTF();
            }
        }
```

How can I modify it to deal with potentially enormous Strings? I've been looking around and can't seem to find a clear answer.

Thanks.

Comment: Is that all I need to do? How does that help?

Comment: can you add your exception here

Comment: IOException on socket listen: java.io.UTFDataFormatException: encoded string too long: 85837 bytes -

It happens when I call dos.writeUTF(xml)

Comment: You client loop has a subtle bug. You break out of the "while" loop as soon as your read input from the input stream. The trouble is that the input stream may return data in chunks as a result of fragmentation, segmentation, and packetization of TCP data.  You need to keep appending data from the input stream to "in" until the input stream has indicated the remote socket has closed.  Otherwise, you may only receive a partial message. As you have it now, it might just work, but eventually will exhibit weird behavior when you go off your subnet.

Comment: Yeah, I felt pretty sketch about that. Will change it. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF%28java.lang.String%29) for `writeUTF()`, it is obvious that the method can only handle strings with up to 65535 encoded bytes.  (The encoded form starts with 2 bytes that give the string byte count).

Your choices are:

- send the String as an array of characters extracted using `String.toCharArray()`,
- use String.getBytes("UTF-8") to UTF8-encode the string explicitly and send the resulting bytes, or
- split it into smaller substrings, send them using writeUTF8, and splice them back together at the other end.

All of these will entail preceding the actual data with a count to tell the other end how much to expect / read.

The other approach is to send/receive the data as text using a `Writer` and `Reader` instead of `DataOutputStream` and `DataInputStream`.

Answer (score -1):

**Use the following to send the data:**

```
Socket s = new Socket();
s.connect(new InetSocketAddress("IP_addr_,Port_no));

OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os);

pw.println("String");
```